# How to check if process is remotely started

Tags: c#, wmi

I run process on remote machine by WMI.

Can I check in the process code (on remote machine) if it is remotely created?

I tried `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo` properties but I didn't find any information. Environment class also doesn't contain any info.

My code use to create remote process (I found it on some forum):

```
                var connOptions = new ConnectionOptions()
                {
                    Username = "user",
                    Password = "password"
                };

            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

            var manScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", "MachineName"), connOptions);

            manScope.Connect();

            var objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            var managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            using (var processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions))
            {
                using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create"))
                {
                    inParams["CommandLine"] = remoteFilePath;

                    using (ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null))
                    {
                        if ((uint)outParams["returnValue"] == 0)
                        {
                            var pid = (uint)outParams["processId"];

                            return pid;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the process with WMI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can detect it or not, but one workaround you can do is pass a command line argument saying something like "remotelyStarted" when you launch via WMI, then in your code just do

```
const string REMOTELY_STARTED_FLAG = "remotelyStarted";

if(Environment.GetComandLineArgs().Contains(REMOTELY_STARTED_FLAG, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //Do code here if it was running remotely.
}
```